# Question How many beads of each color will each necklace have...

Tags: probability

We have 72 red beads,81 yellow beads and 99 white ones and we want to make a necklace,and each necklace should have 9 beads.How many beads of each color will each necklace have??

Comment: Do you mean the expected value? I'm confused. Are we randomly putting beads on necklaces?

Answer (score 1):

You have $252$ total beads, so can make $28$ necklaces with $9$ beads each.  It won't come out even.  The closest you can come is $2$ or $3$ red, $3$ or $4$ yellow, and $3$ or $4$ white.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a slightly different answer than Ross Millikan.

If you are randomly picking beads to be on a given necklace, then the chance of picking a red bead for a given slot on the necklace is: $\frac{72}{252} \approx .29$. So the expected number of red beads is: $9(.29) \approx 2.57$.

For a given slot, the chance of picking a yellow bead is:$\frac{81}{252} \approx .32 \implies$ the expected number of yellow beads on a necklace is: $9(.32) \approx 2.89$.

Finally, for a given slot, the chance of picking a white bead is:$\frac{99}{252} \approx .39 \implies$ the expected number of WHITE beads on a necklace is: $9(.39) \approx 3.53$.

Note that $2.57+2.89+3.53 \approx 9$.